# Как retrofit2 сделать два запроса асинхронно

Tags: android, запрос, retrofit2

Как retrofit2 сделать два запроса асинхронно, чтобы ответы с двух запросов пришли одновременно(или ждали друг друг), а то получаеться то первое прибежит первым, что второе(запрос), но можно Callback засунуть в Callback, тогда все ок, но код не красивый, есть альтернативное решение

Comment: Добавить поле `int count = 0`, при каждом ответе увеличивать на единицу и проверять не стало ли оно равно 2. Как стало, значит оба запроса отработали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение есть. `Retrofit 2` совместим с `RxJava 2`. Если сделать так, чтобы оба запроса возвращали `Observable`, то можно объединить их с помощью `Observable.zip(Observable...)` и подписаться на результирующий `Observable`. Таким образом можно будет в одном колбэке обработать оба ответа.

Comment: если отправит два запроса, если хотя бы один из запросов вернет exception,  оба запроса не сработают или как?

Comment: По умолчанию да. Но можно и более гибко обрабатывать, как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342844/rxjava-how-to-handle-error-with-zip-operator